# Is this a topology? (induced by weak convergence)

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, distribution-theory, weak-convergence, topological-vector-spaces

Let $\mu,\nu$ probability measures on two compact sets respectively $X,Y\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $\Pi(\mu,\nu)$ be the space of measures on $X\times Y$ whose first and second marginals are $\mu,\nu$.
Then let $\gamma_k,\gamma\in\Pi(\mu,\nu)$.

We say that $\gamma_k$ weakly converges to $\gamma$ if for all $g\in C^0(X\times Y)$
$$ \int g d\gamma_k \rightarrow_k \int g d\gamma $$

My question is: can we make sure there exists a topology that induces this convergence?

Comment: What do you mean by $\rightarrow_k$ in the context of the integrals?

Comment: Well $(\int g d\gamma_k)_k$ is a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ so I mean standard convergence in $\mathbb{R}$...

Comment: It’s the restriction of the weak-star topology on the space of measures as the dual of the function space ( versions of the Riesz theorem). That induces this sequence convergence notion.

Comment: I recall that a Riesz theorem guarantees that an element of the dual space has a representation as an integral over some measure. Are you referring to it? Could you help me better understand how this topology is built?

Comment: $C^0(X \times Y)$ are just the continuous functions on $X \times Y$?

Comment: I intend continuous functions to $\mathbb{R}$. This definition comes from a lecture. I think the $g$'s are test functions used in the fashion of distribution theory, but I've never studied it. I usually find test functions to be continuous real functions with compact support, if I remember well. This might be the case but le lecturer might have been sketchy.

Comment: Sorry do you have any more information?

Comment: I don’t know this context very well but I recognise it as a form of the weak-star topology. But I haven’t looked into it enough to write a complete answer.

Comment: Which roughly means that there exist a topology inducing that convergence? Is it so?

Comment: Also, would anything change if instead of $\Pi(\mu,\nu)$ we had $P(X\times Y)$ i.e. the space of probability measures on the product space?

Comment: Not really. And yes, it’s a topology on the space of measures in which convergence of sequences can be thus translated.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So what form of weak-star topology are you thinking of? (it's the first time I actually encounter weak topologies)

Comment: There is only one type of topology that is called the weak-star one.

Comment: Ok, right. Is there anything about my setting that disturbs you in particular? Maybe I can get around it (I don't think so but maybe...). For example, I know there exist a distance that induces a slightly stronger convergence than the weak one.